# How to change the path of custom folder in windows installer?

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms, windows-installer, installation

In my project's installer file I have added a custom folder in the file system. I want this folder to be created at the time of installation with the data added to it. My problem is the path of this folder would be decided at the time of installation, so, I want to consume its "Property" property to change this path. But I am not sure how to use this property in the code. [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/3d6wt21y%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) is the msdn link for the property. Can you please suggest how to consume this in the code and change the path. Also looking forward for some small code example or references.

Comment: Show the code that you have currently so that one can attempt to offer you help

Answer (score 1):

To do it, you need to use Public Properties. Just in table Directory set name of directory with uppercase letters, for example CUSTOMDIR, and during installation transfer this property with command line:

```
msiexec /i installer.msi CUSTOMDIR="C:\temp"
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the response. Can't we set his property programatically?

Comment: Which tool you use to create installer? If WiX I don't sure how it implemented there. 
But when you want change the path? During installing?

Comment: I am using visual studio setup deployment project. I want to set the path before installation begins.

Comment: If you want before installer starts - use the CUSTOMDIR as in example above, and if you want when installer starts - use a custom action with Session.Property property [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa371681(v=vs.85).aspx) to set property CUSTOMDIR.